# jQuery mouseover and mouseleave drop down menus

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, mouseevent

The following displays a menu:

```
<a href="#" id="cityclick">ONZE WAARDEN</a>

<div id="citydrop">
    <div class="dropbottom">
        <div class="dropmid">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">ITC</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">CLUB</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">CULTUUR</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">ROBITICA</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery for is as follows :

```
$("#citydrop").hide();

$("#cityclick").mouseover(function () {
    $("#citydrop").slideDown('slow');
});

$("#citydrop").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#citydrop").slideUp('slow');
});
```

**PROBLEM:**
I'm not able to figure out how to toggle the submenu "citydrop" when the mouse leaves "cityclick" but does not enter "citydrop" yet.

I tried out here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yEHV/)

Comment: Are you saying that when the cursor enters the gap between the link and the menu, you want the menu to slide back up?

Comment: I want the menu to `slideUp` when the mouse hovers anywhere except the dropdown `citydrop`. And when the mouse hovers the dropdown it should not slideUp. And when the mouse leaves the dropdown it should `slideUp`.

Comment: Your jsFiddle fulfills everything you've just said..

Comment: No it doesn't for one case. When my mouse hovers on `cityclick` and then leaves but does not hover on `citydrop`, in that case I want `citydrop` to `slideUp`. Which is not happening.

Comment: Right now my mouse has to hover over `citydrop` is slideUp the menu.

Comment: So tell us exactly where you keep the mouse and the slideup not happening

Comment: Add a background to your citydrop, and you will see  <div id="citydrop" style="background-color:#444;>
your code behave exactly as specified. `<div id="citydrop" style="background-color:#444;>` It also looks like youpre provided with a solution below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use some wrapper on your html, and then call `mouseleave` event on it, like there: http://jsfiddle.net/9yEHV/11/

```
$("#wrapper").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#citydrop").slideUp('slow');
});
```

And wrapper:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="#" id="cityclick" >ONZE WAARDEN</a>
    <!-- rest of your code -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to do?

HTML

```
<ul>
<li class="main-menu">
  ONZE WAARDEN
  <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ITC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CLUB</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CULTUUR</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ROBITICA</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$('.main-menu').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).find('.sub-menu').slideDown();
});

$('.main-menu').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).find('.sub-menu').slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this way it's easy but sigh ! I am not supposed to change the HTML code or add any classes as you did.

Comment: You should have mentioned it in your question

Answer (score 0):

hover plugin includes both mouseenter and mouseleave follwing code works fine for me

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.dropdown').hover(
    function(){

        $(this).children('.dropdown-menu.pricing-drop').slideDown('fast');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).children('.dropdown-menu.pricing-drop').slideUp('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#Dropdown').mouseover(function () {
                    $(this).slideDown();
                });
            });
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#Dropdown').mouseleave(function () {
                    $(this).slideup();
                });
            });
```

i think this might help..